# Who rings the horn (bells) at the Fist of the First Men in Game of Thrones

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones season 2 ep10, when the Night's Watch are at the Fist of the First Men, they hear the bells ringing (horn?) and some of them discuss them: 1 for friends, 2 for Wildlings, 3 for White Walkers etc.

Who rings those bells (horn) and how do they know?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55225/who-blows-the-horn-three-times-announcing-the-white-walkers

Perhaps you can find the answer here?

Comment: not a duplicate; this question asks about particular event in S02E10, while the linked one is probably general.

Comment: **Watch beginning of S03E01 for the answer :-)**. Samwell thinks it's Jon Snow and Qhorin Halfhand, but their rangers' group has been killed/captured. It's the group of crows lead by Lord Commander Jeor Mormont.